# Angular Js Post Operation '500 (Internal Server Error)' Error?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
createEmpModule.controller('createEmpCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.listDatas = function () {
    $http.post("/Common/Common/GetLanguages").then(function (result) {
        $scope.list = result;
    });
}
$scope.listDatas();
});
```

[image: File path image:]

[image: Console error image:]

```
angular.min.js:9827 POST http: //localhost:xxxxx/Common/Common/GetLanguages 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Angular Error Line:

```
xhr.send(post || null);
```

So, function back returns values,

[image: Controller Return Values]

Comment: More like an issue on the server side.

Comment: at least do a search to find out what a 500 error means!

Comment: I've already explored. say you know.

Comment: If you already explored then you should know that you need to debug your server code

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you are making an `$http.post()` without sending any data.

```
$scope.listDatas = function () {
    $http.post("/Common/Common/GetLanguages", [dataObjectGoesHere]).then(function (result) {
        $scope.list = result;
    });
}
```

My guess is that you want .get() instead.

```
$scope.listDatas = function () {
    $http.get("/Common/Common/GetLanguages").then(function (result) {
        $scope.list = result;
    });
}
```

The second thing I will say is **check your server error logs**! They will hold the key to what is causing your 500 error. I am willing to bet $1.00 that you are getting an error about trying to POST without data to a location expecting a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug solution.
It was not the object type from the control object.
I created a new model and I solved.

Server Error in '/' Application.

? ?
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.SByte, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.